# bootstrap vue (b-form-rating) shows blue outline when clicked in chrome browser

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

An annoying blue outline appears every time I do a click on a `b-form-rating` component. Any ideas of how to get rid of this? Nothing that I've tried so far has helped.

[image: Component with blue outline]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's triggered by a `:focus` pseudo-class CSS rule.

[image: CSS rule]

You can should be able to disable them by setting them to `inherit !important`.

For example:

```
.form-control:focus {
   border-color: inherit !important!;
   box-shadow: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: .form-control:focus { box-shadow: none;} works for me, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `border-color` with transparent value, unset the box-shadow and avoid to use `!important`

```js
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: The accepted answer @iLLia12, recommends bad practices (the use of !important and it doesn't work). My answer is a lot closer to what worked for you (box-shadow: none) and as a result I am baffled as to how it is the accepted answer.

Comment: sorry, i liked your answer and i down-voted it accidentally, so +1

Answer (score 0):

How about using the *no-border* prop ?

```
<b-form-rating ... no-border ...>
```

doc: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-rating#borderless